# Select all values in same group using value in group

Tags: select, query, order-by

I have following query:

```
SELECT
    SubstitutionGroupID,
    Material.Number,
    Material.DescriptionEN
FROM
    MaterialSubstitution
    INNER JOIN Material on Material.MaterialID = MaterialSubstitution.MaterialID
ORDER BY
    SubstitutionGroupID, Material.Number
```

Result example:

```
SubstitutionGroupID Number      DescriptionEN
52494               303H603021  HINGE R
52494               3H603020    HINGE R
52495               303H604031  TRAY EJECT
52495               3H604030    TRAY EJECT (1/2)
```

I want have a query where I can define one number and recieve all numbers in one SubstitutionGroupID.

Comment: So your query needs to be:  Given a number, display all the substitution numbers for that?  E.g. From your example data given `3H603020` you want to display both `3H603020` and `303H603021`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after if I have understood your requirements:

```
DECLARE @Number NVARCHAR(30);
SET @Number = '3H603020';

SELECT
    ms.SubstitutionGroupID,
    subs.Number,
    subs.DescriptionEN
FROM
    MaterialSubstitution AS ms
    INNER JOIN Material  AS m ON m.MaterialID = ms.MaterialID
    INNER JOIN Material  AS subs ON subs.MaterialID = ms.MaterialID
WHERE
    m.Number = @Number
ORDER BY
    ms.SubstitutionGroupID, subs.Number
```

You need to join back to `Material` again to find the "substitutions" (hence the alias `subs`) for a given `Material.Number`